# dynamically styling last row's <hr> divider

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list of items that are being dynamically populated using angularjs.  Each row is divided with a hr divider.  On the last row that's generated, I would like that hr divider to be a bit bolder and different.  How would I go about doing this?

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data.list track by $index" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <h4><img class="icon" src="{{item.icon}}" height="30" width="30"> &nbsp;<strong>{{item.type}}</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font size = 2><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" style="color:green"/> Done</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-edit pointer" ng-click="c.onWidget(item)"/></h4> 
  <p><strong>My Stuff:</strong> &nbsp;{{item.mystuff}}</p>
  <p><strong>Your Stuff:</strong> &nbsp;{{item.yourstuff}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$last` in your `ng-repeat` to apply a class with `ng-class`.

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in bar">
  ...
  <hr ng-class="{true : 'last-hr-class', false : 'regular-hr-class'}[$last]"/>
</div>
```

FYI: available keys inside `ng-repeat` are 
`$index`
`$first`
`$middle`
`$last`
`$even`
`$odd`

More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$index` and the length of your list to determine when you are at the last item:

```
<hr ng-class="{'bolder': $index == data.list.length - 1 }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with CSS's **[:last-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)** pseudo-selector:

```css
hr:last-of-type {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  color: #333; /* Old IE */
  background-color: #333; /* Modern Browsers */ 
}
```

```html
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
```

Note that your Angular loop will also output the parent `<div>`, so you would need to target this div as well:

```
div > hr:last-of-type { }
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This wouldn't work as there's only 1 `<hr>` element in its parent.  You could move the `:last-of-type` to the parent class and target the `<hr>` within.

Comment: Ahh yes; I was a little thrown by the lack of the closing `</div>` in the original code. I'll update my code to cover this :)